# How to add a theme

Tags: openshift, ghost

I just wired up an instance of ghost on openshift.  Then I downloaded a new theme and added it to content/themes.  How do I replace the old theme, casper, with the new [Portfolio](https://www.gavick.com/download/ghost-themes/ghost-themes-portfolio) theme?  I tried going into Makefile and changing:

```
theme: node_modules
    @cp -r node_modules/ghost/content/themes/casper content/themes/
```

to

```
theme: node_modules
    @cp -r node_modules/ghost/content/themes/Portfolio content/themes/
```

I logged into the management console on openshift and [checked settings](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-openshift/) and did not see any options to change themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `http://youropenhosturl/ghost` and you will be redirected to an administrative page for Ghost.  There is a settings button here that will allow you to change themes.